# Issur Doraisa from Trup?

Tags: halacha, trop-cantillation, riddle

What Halacha (Issur Doraisia) do we learn out from a Trup and which word is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is Geinavas Daas of a Gentile, Which according to the Ritva is a Doraisia. The Posuk says:

לא תגנבו ולא תכחשו ולא תשקרו **איש בעמיתו**

Therefore t first thought it would only be People who are עמיתו. The Ritva says **NO**, the words
  בעמיתו applies to the last two Issurim in the Posuk לא תכחשו ולא תשקרו and since there is an
 אתנחתא under the words of לא תגנבו and the אתנחת like a comma indicates a break therfore the פסוק consists of two parts לא תגנבו – don’t steal (from anyone) בעמיתו – you shall not deny falsely and you shall not lie to another (Yid). We, therefore, have an איסור דאורייתא the איסור of גניבת דעת , based on the Trop of a certain word.

Comment: Don't most/all halachot that are based on derashot depend on our mesora for where the pauses (etnachta, but also sof pasuk and the lower pauses) go? Our understanding of the meaning of the text is dependent in all cases on our understanding of the punctuation.

Comment: In other words, I'd say that this derasha depends not on the trup so much as on our masoretic understanding of the structure of the text, which is also expressed by the trup.

Comment: Good stuff again

Comment: You realize Issac you Just said nothing to change the answer just made it sound intlectual

Comment: can you post the source of this Ritva?

Comment: @whiskey He didn't change the answer, just made it completely non-unique because every drasha in the gemara is also based on trop.

Answer (score 0):

> The Vilna Gaon points out that in the
>   entire Torah, the word ונכרתה, which
>   means that a sin is punishable by כרת,
>   always has the same cantillation,
>   which is called תביר – broken. This
>   alludes to the fact that somebody who
>   commits such a sin will be spiritually
>   broken and cut off from Hashem. There
>   is one exception. On the verse (12:15)
>   which says כי כל אוכל חמץ ונכרתה – any
>   person who eats chometz on Pesach will
>   be spiritually cut off – the
>   cantillation on the word ונכרתה is
>   called גרשיים – sending away This
>   alludes to the fact that in contrast
>   to every other sin which is punishable
>   by כרת, the punishment for eating
>   chometz on Pesach is גירושין – exile
>   and spiritual divorce.

http://halachafortoday.com/Parsha.aspx

Comment: That's not really a Halachic consequence, is it?

Comment: Best answer I could find so far

Comment: @Isaac Moses I disagree. Assuming that there is a practical difference between גירושין and standard כרת, there is no indication of this נ"מ other than the difference in cantillation. (Of course your point about מסורה and causation is still valid.)

Comment: @WAF, My point here is to question whether there is a practical difference between גירושין and standard כרת. In what way would this distinction affect our behavior? Do the Halachot of how Heavenly reward and punishment work, in and of themselves, constitute practical Halacha?

Comment: My point on the other answer doesn't apply here, since here, the derivation is from the name of the note, not just from the masoretic structure of the text.